# Can a simple write to one variable modify the state of another?

Tags: multithreading

Taken from Operating Systems - Principles and Practices Vol 3. Chapter 5 Question 4. This isn't homework, I'm now curious.

```
Suppose that you mistakenly create an automatic (local) variable v in one
thread t1 and pass a pointer to v to another thread t2. Is it possible that a
write by t1 to some variable other than v will change the state of v as
observed by t2? If so, explain how this can happen and give an example. If
not, explain why not.
```

I don't think this is possible unless T1 declared v within a lower level scope, which was popped off the stack via modification to the afore-mentioned unrelated variable, followed by a swift reallocation of that memory to a new variable. But what I've described isn't a simple write, and that new variable isn't v anymore; at least not to T1.

Were this possible, I think it would imply that a simple write to any unrelated variable could somehow change another memory location even in single threaded programs.

So is this possible?

Comment: Since both t1 and t2 have now access to `v`, it depends on how both threads access that variable. In case they modify `v` without synchronization, your scenario is possible, but that would be undefined behavior.. If only one thread will access `v`, it is not possible.. Assumption here is the C++ memory model.